# How can i maintain permalink structure and avoid a 404 error when loading external content?

Tags: url-rewriting, database, urls, 404-error

I created a page called Catalog and also a template called page-catalog.php. The url looks like this now:
sitename.com/catalog

So far so good, however i use some custom php stuff to list products from another database. So when i click on a brand in this page, i want to use an url like this:
sitename.com/catalog/brands/brandname

But obviously because the data is not coming from Wordpress, it gives me 404. Is it possible to use the same page-catalog.php file if the url has more parts?

I could use an url like this:
sitename.com/catalog/?brand=brandname
But this solution is not so sep friendly.

Comment: Your question really isn't about *disabling the 404 page*, as it is about *how to combine external DB data with WordPress data*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a WordPress rewrite (as opposed to mod-rewrite) to solve the issue.

```
function createRewriteRules( $rules ){
    $newrules = null;
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules["catalog/?$"] = "index.php?page=xx";
    $rules = $newrules + $rules;
    return $rules;
}

add_action('rewrite_rules_array', 'createRewriteRules');
```

You'll need to flush the rules:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Your page-catalog.php file could then sniff the original url and do some processing as required.

Comment: Thanks, i just tried it, but it's not working. .com/catalog loads up my index.php, .com/catalog/anything gives me 404.php

Comment: Did you flush the rules?  (A quick way is in WP Admin, change your permalink structure to something different, save, and then change it back and save).

Comment: Also, try with the function in a plugin as opposed to functions.php

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks! Maybe i can mess with the add_action location, like add_action=init to make this work from the functions.php

Comment: It's most likely that functions.php doesn't work because it loads fairly late in the bootstrap process, loading the rewrite rules too late may have other unintended consquences - they're used to determine a bunch of things, most importantly what template to load.

Comment: Investiage a mu (must use) plugin, which acts a lot like an early loading functions.php file